# kubernetes custom log aggregator in node.js Or fluentd

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

I am looking to save the application logs to mongo or flat files.

I looked at fluentd, but it saves to elasticsearch, which is quite heavy.

I was looking for mongo, since the db size is quite small.

Is there a way to write custom logger or implement the same in fluentd.

Also is it possible to have a thin layer between fluentd server and database to selectively save the logs to db, based on log levels.

Comment: does this thread help: https://docs.fluentd.org/how-to-guides/apache-to-mongodb?

Comment: did you take a look at loki ? its really easy to install with helm https://grafana.com/go/webinar/intro-to-loki-like-prometheus-but-for-logs/?pg=oss-loki&plcmt=hero-txt